# /root/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: sapiauthentication

Tags: ssh

My virtual environment/system:

```
# uname -a
Linux X 4.9.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.303-1 (2022-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/debian_version
9.13
# ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
#
```

I unable to figure out how to I disable `SAPIAuthentication`

```
# /usr/bin/sftp -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -b /root/test X@X.Y.Z -v
/root/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: sapiauthentication
/root/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
# cat ~/.ssh/config
Host X.Y.Z
  SAPIAuthentication no
#
```

Please advise)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where this "SAPIAuthentication" came from? OpenSSH never knew anything about such thing — exactly what it is telling you, a "bad configuration option:. I think this is just the syntax error, probably it was meant to be "GSSAPIAuthentication" (which *is* a valid OpenSSL configuration parameter). So just remove this.

Comment: I'm not really sure why any of downvotes... I meant to replicate `-o GSSAPIAuthentication=No` and somehow during copy and paste, I manage to introduce a typo, which I didn't realized until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable `SAPIAuthentication` but you could disable `GSSAPIAuthentication`.